# c# Object properties is loading from cache

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, object

in my win-form application, there is a method that combines some items that have been created previously, when the code is the first time to run, everything is fine, but in second and later runs combined items have the wrong length.

the code reads items from a SQL server using LINQ that has object type named "BetaData"

BetaData has a property named "Length" that is double.
 I have another list that processed items is stored in name "PartList" of type "ModifiedPartList".

in method length property changes for some items, but nothing gets stored or saved on SQL. 
this is the main method:

```
private List<ModifiedPartList> CombinePartList(ProgressBar Bar)
        {
            PartList.Clear();

            List<BetaData> PartsinOrder = new List<BetaData>();
            foreach (int view in Globals.Views)
            {
                List<int> OrdersInView = new List<int>();
                foreach (Tuple<int, int> tuple in Globals.Orders)
                {
                    if (tuple.Item1 == view)
                    {
                        if (!OrdersInView.Contains(tuple.Item2))
                            OrdersInView.Add(tuple.Item2);
                    }
                }
                if(OrdersInView.Count>0)
                {
                    OrdersInView.Sort();
                    foreach (int order in OrdersInView)
                    {
                        //this is the section that problem occurs:
                        var parts = from BetaData in BetaContext.BetaDatas
                                    where BetaData.ProjectName == Globals.ProjectName &&
                                          BetaData.ProjectCode == Globals.ProjectCode &&
                                          BetaData.ParentItem != Globals.ProjectName + "(" + Globals.ProjectCode + ")" &&
                                          BetaData.View == view &&
                                          BetaData.Order == order
                                    select BetaData;
                        PartsinOrder.Clear();
                        PartsinOrder = parts.ToList();
                        foreach(BetaData part in PartsinOrder)
                        {

                            Bar.PerformStep();
                        }
                    }

                }
                PartsinOrder.Clear();
            }
            return PartList;
        }
```

in the section that i have commented as problem location when the code is running for the second time, optimized length property is loaded to items instead of their original value from SQL. i cannot understand that because each time i read all items from SQL server. 
the point is in this stage after that i ran the method for several times and getting the wrong results when i close the program and start it again, on first run results are true.
after selecting from SQL and converting it to list, i review items and their properties in list, and they are all true, but in foreach loop when each part comes into loop their Length property is wrong.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the method? Also, you haven't posted the code where you do the actual saving of the changes.

Comment: And may I advice you to reduce the complexity of the `CombinePartList` method by splitting it up into smaller methods? The length and amount of nesting due to the many if/else constructs makes it very difficult to read and understand.

Comment: I can see a few calls to `SaveLength()`. Is it possible you're overwriting the values in the database so when you run it for the second time you're actually loading those saved/changed values back in?

Comment: @PeterBons yes i have, there is no residuals after running the method that may affect next run,  i have debugged it step by step, and when sql selection is running, everything is fine, but when objects are passed into foreach loop they get their last edited value.

Comment: @HandbagCrab as you can see in begining of the method each time method runs "ClearSavedLengthes();" clear all parameters that have bin saved.

Comment: @PeterBons you'r right, but i have splitted all other calculations in smaller methodss this methode is just a decition. 
post edited, "saveLength" method is added

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework to retrieve your data? If so, when you change the values it changes them locally and cache's those changes, so if you were to keep the application open and call CombinePartList a second time it will load the results from the local cache rather than going out to the database to retrieve the original values. There's a reload/refresh function in EF that forces an entity to be reloaded from the database but you'd have to call it for each ModifiedPartList item.

Comment: @HandbagCrab not, i am using LINQ to retrieve data from SQL Database. does linq have such e "reload/refresh" function?

Comment: I've no idea. I've not used Linq to SQL.

Comment: I did find [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dinesh.kulkarni/2008/05/23/linq-to-sql-tips-6-how-to-refresh-given-datacontext-wont-stomp-on-your-objects/). Give it a try.

Comment: @HandbagCrab thank you, it solved the problem, i refreshed the DataContext after rtrieving them from SQL and i think its now solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was solved using [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dinesh.kulkarni/2008/05/23/linq-to-sql-tips-6-how-to-refresh-given-datacontext-wont-stomp-on-your-objects/) article and refreshing context after retrieving data from SQL